# Aerospike: How to use LLIST as LSTACK

Tags: aerospike

I am currently using Aerospike 3.7.3. LSTACK being largely used and want to migrate to LLIST. Please clarify my below queries.

1. How to migrate data from LSTACK to LLIST without affecting the keys. OR in other ways without affecting the clients using it.
2. How to implement the function of LSTACK using LLIST. I am currently using python client 2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aerospike's LLIST API is now deprecated and there's a native `list`
>   data type available.
>
> http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html

**Migrating data:**

LLIST has a different API and control structures so you will need to migrate your data for each record. The fastest would be a simple Lua script that runs on the server and just reads all the stack items and copies them into a list using the logic below.

**Implementing stack:**

The LLIST API is actually implemented as Lua functions on the server already so you can write your own Lua code to wrap these functions and implement stack logic on top of LLIST. Then just call those Lua functions from the client driver. This will be just as fast and maintains the write-lock on records so the operations are atomic.

The basic logic is to use the LLIST as the holder for the stack items and use another bin on the record to hold a index number that maintains the position (or count) of the number of items in the list.

- PUSH - Add the item to the list. Increment the index number.
- POP - Lookup the index number. Decrement this number. Return the item
  at the lookup value position of the list.

---

Here's more info and code examples on building a stack, queue or map on top of a LLIST from an Aerospike engineering team member:

https://github.com/helipilot50/aerospike-LDT-techniques

Comment: Nice reply. My problem is I have around 100G of data stored in Aerospike used by multiple clients round the clock.  I need to do this LSTACK to LLIST migration without affecting the operation.  

It would be great if  you could suggest a right methodology to handle my problem?

Comment: There's no easy way around this. The clients will need to be updated to use the custom Lua functions you write to maintain the stack on top of LLIST. You can use a bin to signal if a record has been updated or not, then the client can check this and use the appropriate method (either old stack api or new Lua functions). This would mean updating the clients code first, then running a migration script that goes through all the data and sets this special bin value. Once it's all done, you can update the client logic again and remove this bin.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mani Gandham.  This serves my purpose